# How to delete the file from the folder in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter-3

I saved the name of the file in the database and deleted the name form the database but having problem with the folder file.Can you guys please help me out with that.following is my controller function for delete.I first pass the id from the database and delete the file name from database.I also grab the name of the file in array.But how to delete the file.my file location is in root name "mms/musics/".

```
public function delete($id){
            $this->load->model('main');
            $this->common_model->delete('id',$id,'audio');


        foreach($data as $row){
            $data['id'] = $row->id;
            $data['file_name'] = $row->audio; 
        }
        redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);




        $this->main->delete($data);

        //$this->load->helper("file");
        //delete_files(base_url()."musics/$data['name']");


    }//delete
```

please guys help me out..

Comment: You can not delete file over URL path. Only over absolute or relative file path i.e. `FCPATH."musics/$data['name']"`.

Comment: It is deleting form the database but not from the folder i tried out like: delete_files(FCPATH."musics/".$data['name']);@Tpojka

Comment: Is `musics` directory next to `index.php` and what is `var_dump($name)`?

Comment: You are unsetting `$data` array in your loop. Use different variable name inside like `$data2`, but also your file should be `$row->name`.

Comment: its working now ......Thanks @Tpojka

Comment: Happy coding. #SOreadytohelp

Answer (score 0):

To delete file from system you need to use function unlink(). This will delete your file located in assets folder.

Before perform delete query of after query execution you need to pass proper file name into unlink function to delete file from system.

```
unlink('assets/text.txt');
```